# Service returns empty array

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, rxjs

I am working on a personal project and I have a service that returns an array of images from firebases storage. The problem is that when I subscribe to the observable I get an empty array. When I open the array all the data is there. The problem is when I try to do something with the array I get undefined (for example console.log(myArray[0]) is undefined). If I'm correct the problem is that observable are asynchronous and that is why I get the empty array. My question is, how can I fix this problem?

Here is the service

```
  getImagesForChosenRestaurant(id: string): Observable<any> {
    this.imageList = []
      this.imageRef = ref(storage, `food/${id}`)
      listAll(this.imageRef).then(res => {
        res.items.forEach(item => {
          getDownloadURL(item).then(url => {
            this.imageList.push(url);
          })
        })
      })
      return of(this.imageList);
  }
```

And here is the subscription

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.restaurantService.getImagesForChosenRestaurant(params['id']).subscribe((foodPic: any) => {
        this.foodImages = foodPic;
      })
    })
  }
```

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: return of(this.imageList);  Will be executed before any pushes to the list

Comment: And how can I prevent that?

Comment: Depends. Is getDownloadURL really async?

Comment: That is from firebase so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map` method to convert your array of items from `listAll` to array of promises for `getDownloadURL`. After that just use `Promise.all()` with rxjs `from`.

```
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

getImagesForChosenRestaurant(id: string): Observable<string[]> {
  const wrapperFn = async () => {
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `food/${id}`);
    const listAllResult = await listAll(imageRef);
    const imagesDownloadUrlsPromises = listAllResult.items.map((item) =>
      getDownloadURL(item)
    );
    return Promise.all(imagesDownloadUrlsPromises);
  };
  return from(wrapperFn());
}
```

Comment: This one works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  async getImagesForChosenRestaurant(id: string): Promise<void> {
    this.imageList = []
      this.imageRef = ref(storage, `food/${id}`)
      const list = await listAll(this.imageRef);
      list.items.forEach(async item => {
          const url = await getDownloadURL(item);
          this.imageList.push(url);
      })
      return of(this.imageList);
  }
```

Comment: I doubt this will work. forEach is not async ‘aware’ so the await in the loop won’t have the expected result.

Comment: ok maybe you're right , so i add `async` to the forEach loop

Comment: I have tried this and it's still not working

Comment: `ref()` is not an async function?

Comment: forEach is not awaitable, so there is no way to use it with `async`. If you switch that code to plain `for` loop with `await` inside - it will work. But the cons of this solution is its sequental execution, one after another. With combination of Promise.all() and .map() you can fire them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getImagesForChosenRestaurant(id: string): Observable<string[]> {
  const imageRef = ref(storage, `food/${id}`);
  return from(listAll(imageRef)).pipe(
    switchMap((res) => forkJoin(res.items.map(getDownloadURL)))
  );
}
```